# Convert factor to integer

Tags: r, integer, coercion

I am manipulating a data frame using the reshape package. When using the melt function, it factorizes my value column, which is a problem because a subset of those values are integers that I want to be able to perform operations on.

Does anyone know of a way to coerce a factor into an integer? Using `as.character()` will convert it to the correct character, but then I cannot immediately perform an operation on it, and `as.integer()` or `as.numeric()` will convert it to the number that system is storing that factor as, which is not helpful.

Thank you!

Jeff

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/r-how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-in-r-without-a-loss-of-informat

Comment: This Q is NOT similar to the duplicate one. Many many people are getting NAs from the top answer (see comments). The answer that works in that post is in the middle (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399425) but is stated as not belonging to the post. I suggest it is added to this post. So much wasted time for such a simple issue.

Comment: @luchonacho if NAs are a key issue for this question, that should be mentioned in the question. I don't see "many many people," I see a few comments about either non-numeric values that weren't mentioned, or entirely different use-cases like the answer you linked to. If you want a new question that's focused on handling NAs and/or non-numeric strings, you should post one

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can combine the two functions; coerce to characters thence to numerics:

```
> fac <- factor(c("1","2","1","2"))
> as.numeric(as.character(fac))
[1] 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get the warning message: "NAs introduced by coercion." What does this mean?

Comment: Or does this just mean that some of them were not numbers to start with?

Comment: @Jeff it means that some of the characters aren't numbers, so they get  converted to `NA` when you use `as.numeric(....)`. Look at `levels(fac)` and `as.numeric(levels(fac))` replacing `fac` with your factor variable to see which are being coerced to `NA`.

Comment: you can use convert() from hablar to do this. `df %>% convert(num(column_name))` to safely coerce from factor to numerical

Answer (score 80):

Quoting directly from the help page for `factor`:

To transform a factor f to its original numeric values, `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is recommended and slightly more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(f))`.