# Converting string to numeric

Tags: string, r

I've imported a test file and tried to make a histogram

```
pichman <- read.csv(file="picman.txt", header=TRUE, sep="/t")   
hist <- as.numeric(pichman$WS)
```

However, I get different numbers from values in my dataset. Originally I thought that this  because I had text, so I deleted the text:

```
table(pichman$WS)    
ws <- pichman$WS[pichman$WS!="Down" & pichman$WS!="NoData"]
```

However, I am still getting very high numbers does anyone have an idea?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128

Comment: you can use `hablar::retype` after importing the csv file and it will convert all columns to an appropiate data type, i.e. never to factor. So just add `pichman %>% retype`.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I suspect you are having a problem with factors. For example,

```
> x = factor(4:8)
> x
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
Levels: 4 5 6 7 8
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> as.numeric(as.character(x))
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
```

Some comments:

- You mention that your vector contains the characters "Down" and "NoData". What do expect/want `as.numeric` to do with these values?
- In `read.csv`, try using the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`
- Are you sure it's `sep="/t` and not `sep="\t"`
- Use the command `head(pitchman)` to check the first fews rows of your data
- Also, it's very tricky to guess what your problem is when you don't provide data. A minimal working example is always preferable. For example, I can't run the command `pichman <- read.csv(file="picman.txt", header=TRUE, sep="/t")` since I don't have access to the data set.

Comment: I added a timing in a new answer. +1 for you as you had it correct and gave all options.

Comment: thank a million! i deleted the values "Down" and "NoData" after i saw that it is not only numbers and yes i got my slashes mixed up

Answer (score 14):

As csgillespie said. stringsAsFactors is default on TRUE, which converts any text to a factor. So even after deleting the text, you still have a factor in your dataframe.

Now regarding the conversion, there's a more optimal way to do so. So I put it here as a reference :

```
> x <- factor(sample(4:8,10,replace=T))
> x
 [1] 6 4 8 6 7 6 8 5 8 4
Levels: 4 5 6 7 8
> as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
 [1] 6 4 8 6 7 6 8 5 8 4
```

To show it works.

The timings :

```
> x <- factor(sample(4:8,500000,replace=T))
> system.time(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.00    0.11 
> system.time(as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

It's a big improvement, but not always a bottleneck. It gets important however if you have a big dataframe and a lot of columns to convert.