# Convert string to numeric in a list in R

Tags: r, string

I am new to R. I am working on a dataset which is a large list, there is a column with numbers and strings. I want to remove the string and convert to numeric.

I have `100,000+`

I want 100,000 and numeric

Comment: Duplicate Question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931545/converting-string-to-numeric

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, as the question here seems to involve converting strings that include non numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` to transform the string:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", "100,000+"))
# [1] 1e+05
```

Here, all characters, except digits and `.`, are removed before applying `as.numeric`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with that