# Convert Factor columns in data frame to numeric type columns

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert factor to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/convert-factor-to-integer)
>   [R - How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric in R without a loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/r-how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-in-r-without-a-loss-of-informat)

I have read a text file where some of the columns with real number are read as factors into a data frame.  How do i convert the factoe columns into numeric columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/convert-factor-to-integer

Comment: -1 for duplication. Suggest closing. It's also a FAQ _and_ explicitly answered on the help page.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question targets at the problem of converting _all_ factor columns in a data frame automatically. The solution in the "duplicate" is not applicable: `as.numeric` does not work on data frames.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your column with numbers got read in as a factor is that either there's something somewhere that makes the column not number-only or you've messed up the decimal character (this being the special case of the first problem). If your decimal is not `.`, you can specify a new one via argument `dec`, e.g. `dec = ","`.

Answer (score 1):

This is [FAQ 7.10](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f).

But rather than converting after the fact, why not read them in correctly by either specifying the `colClasses` argument if using `read.table` or one of its variants, or better yet, figuring out what character(s) in the file is(are) convincing R that your numbers are not all numbers and fixing the source file (or best, do both).