# How to convert the datatype "Factor" to the datatype "numeric" in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)

I want to count (and later on plot the count of) the unique values of an array:

```
data = c(1,2,3,4,5,2.1,1,2,1,2,1,4,5,7,8,9,6,5,4,3,2,2,1)
uniCount = as.data.frame(table(data))
uniCount$cumsum = cumsum(uniCount$Freq)

str(uniCount)

plot (uniCount$data, uniCount$Freq)
plot (uniCount$data, uniCount$cumsum)
```

But, the values of the column `data` is not 'numeric' but 'Factor'. For me it seems that the datatype Factor is an associative array of Strings. When I use `as.numeric(uniCount$data)` the result gives "1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10"

How can I convert the datatype "Factor" to the datatype "numeric"?
Or how can I prevent that R converts my numeric values to a Facotr?

Comment: And [Convert factor to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4798343/210673).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may work for you

```
as.numeric(attr(uniCount$data,"levels"))
```

or

```
as.numeric(levels(uniCount$data))
```

if you dont want factors try

```
data = c(1,2,3,4,5,2.1,1,2,1,2,1,4,5,7,8,9,6,5,4,3,2,2,1)
uniCount = as.data.frame(table(data),stringsAsFactors =F)
uniCount$cumsum = cumsum(uniCount$Freq)
```

EDIT:

thanks @Carl Witthoft, but `?factor` says that `as.numeric(levels(uniCount$data))[uniCount$data]` is recommended and slightly more efficient than  `as.numeric(as.character(uniCount$data))`"

Comment: Heed the words of The R-Inferno (and I believe it's in the R-FAQ as well):  always convert using `as.numeric(as.character(levels(blah)))` or you may not get what you expect.

Comment: I feel it also should be mentioned that this is explicitly explained in the documentation of `?factor` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `plyr` package can make it easier to do such operations without getting character/factor variables.

```
library(plyr)
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,2.1,1,2,1,2,1,4,5,7,8,9,6,5,4,3,2,2,1))
ddply(d, "x", summarize, Freq=length(x))
```