# Converting a factor to numeric after relabeling

Tags: r, data-structures, integer, coercion

This question is related to [Convert factor to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/convert-factor-to-integer) and [How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) but has a slightly different problem with type coercion.

The two former question seem to deal with cases were a factor is explicitly constructed from a previously existing vector of class `numeric` or of class `integer` without relabeling the `levels`. In these cases:

```
f <- factor(c("1","2","1","2"))
as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
```

returns

```
# [1] 1 2 1 2
```

but when I relabel the levels:

```
f <- factor(c("1","2","1","2"))
f <- factor(f,
            levels = c(1, 2),
            labels = c("a", "b"))
as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
```

I will get

```
# [1] NA NA NA NA
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

whereas

```
as.numeric(f)
```

returns

```
# [1] 1 2 1 2
```

What is the right procedure in such a case to get the original values back? Is it just `as.numeric(f)`?

In case it's relevant:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 RC (2014-10-28 r66890)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_IE.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_IE.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: Once you re-label, the original values are forever lost. `as.numeric()` will always return 1 for the first level, 2 for the second, etc. It does not matter what the actual/original labels or values were.

Comment: That's good. I was afraid that in such a case `as.numeric()` might somehow return the original values which would wreak havoc if I were to submit to someone my data frame as a numeric only data frame by using `as.numeric()` on all (factor) columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for a certainty that there is an exact correspondence between the original levels and the underlying factor/integer encoding, then you can use as.numeric(f). But ... if the original vector were

```
 f <- factor(c("2","3","2","3"))
```

And you changed the level-labels to alpha values, then as.numeric(f) would give misleading results. The factor encoding always starts with `1L`.